# Querying a AWS DynamoDB Server with just the range key in swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use a query function on an aws dynamodb server and return the value of an index using only its range key. Basically I want a user to be able to find other users using only this range key. My program generates a random code from one user, and the other user is supposed to be able to find that user without knowing their user id and just knowing their random code. At the moment, when I query, it only returns users matching the same user id as the device that is querying, so I am trying to query for just the random code (which is the range key). Here is my code:

```
let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
        queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#randomCode = :randomCode AND #userId = :userId"

        queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = [
            "#userId": "userId",
            "#randomCode": "randomCode"
        ]
        queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
            ":randomCode": passedCode,
            ":userId": AWSIdentityManager.default().identityId
        ]


        // 2) Make the query
        dynamoDbObjectMapper.query(Timestamps.self, expression: queryExpression) { (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            if output == nil {
                print("Nill output")
            }
            if output != nil {
                if output!.items.count == 0 {
                    print("code not found")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
                        animation.duration = 0.07
                        animation.repeatCount = 4
                        animation.autoreverses = true
                        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.codeTextField.center.x - 10, y: self.codeTextField.center.y))
                        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.codeTextField.center.x + 10, y: self.codeTextField.center.y))
                        self.codeTextField.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for timestamps in output!.items {
                        let timestampItem = timestamps as? Timestamps
                        //print(timestampItem?._songURI as! String)
                        let currentSong = timestampItem?._songURI as! String
                        let currentTimestamp = timestampItem?._timestamp
                        let currentTimestampDouble = currentTimestamp as! Double
                        //print(currentTimestampDouble)
                        self.playSync(currentSong: currentSong, currentTimestamp: currentTimestampDouble)
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

If I pass the hash key as nil or don't pass it at all, aws returns an error that the query did not contain a hash key. How do I query for a hash key I do not know, or how do I just query for the range key?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform that query using the index you currently have. You need to create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the table with `randomCode` as the primary key of that index. Then you can query by only `randomCode` by specifying that the query use the Global Secondary Index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have made a secondary index, however I cannot find online how to switch to that secondary index in swift (it only seems to come up in java). Would you happen to know how to or know of any documentation that tells me how? If not thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Sorry but I don't use Swift. Where is the documentation for the Swift SDK for AWS?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html This seems to be the only documentation from amazon that I can find. If anyone sees anything else lmk

Comment: From that link I got to the API reference here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/ and I believe you would be creating a `AWSDynamoDBQueryInput` object as documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBQueryInput.html, so you would want to set the `indexName` field to the name of the new Global Secondary Index, just like in any other AWS SDK.